# Select those record which is continue in date

Tags: date, continue

I want to select those record which have city Indore and DOB is continue date means i want only 4 row ID is 1,2 and 4,5. How can i write select query.

My Table like

```
ID Name    City        DOB
1  Ravi    Indore      1978-09-01 
2  Raja    Indore      1978-09-02 
3  Rakesh  Indore      1978-09-04 
4  Rahul   Indore      1978-09-11 
5  John    Indore      1978-09-12
6  Rocky   Indore      1978-09-18
7  Vijay   Indore      1978-09-20
```

Comment: Is this in a database? which database? What query have you tried that didn't work?

Comment: This sounds like a gaps and islands problem.